# How do I know which version of a .so my APK is running? (armeabi-v7a or armeabi)

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

According to my `Application.mk`, I am compiling both a armeabi-v7a AND a armeabi version of a C++ shared library.  How do I know which version is being loaded at runtime?  Is there a similar setting for the Java code, or is that an ill-formed question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to know it in native code, than try doing like in hello-jni ndk sample `android-ndk\samples\hello-jni\jni\hello-jni.c`

```
#if defined(__arm__)
  #if defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__)
    #if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON"
      #endif
    #else
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a"
      #endif
    #endif
  #else
   #define ABI "armeabi"
  #endif
#elif defined(__i386__)
   #define ABI "x86"
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
   #define ABI "x86_64"
#elif defined(__mips64)  /* mips64el-* toolchain defines __mips__ too */
   #define ABI "mips64"
#elif defined(__mips__)
   #define ABI "mips"
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
   #define ABI "arm64-v8a"
#else
   #define ABI "unknown"
#endif

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI " ABI ".");
```

Comment: Nice, thanks.  How do I toggle which ABI is built in Eclipse?  It seems like this should be a simple thing, but all the posts I found are NDK-only.  Don't regular Java programmers choose which ABI to target as well?

Comment: regular java programmers would rather use standard `make` with cross-compiling. You can also use cross-compiling for android, but it is a lot easier to use ndk's `ndk-build` and [Application.mk (APP_ABI variable)](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Check your Processor Architecture using android framework api. According to that particular .so loaded.

Comment: you can also check in this app. It show processor Architecture inside hardware navigation option.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoneandsiminfo&hl=en